# How to manually create spec.ts files for components?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

As the questions says, I want to create the spec.ts files by hand since devs turned off the automatic generation when they created the components.
I copied over the one spec.ts file that they had into every single component, so it looks like this except the component name is different for each one:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu.component';

describe('NavMenuComponent', () => {
  let component: NavMenuComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavMenuComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NavMenuComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavMenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

However, I did "npm run test" and it failed for pretty much every one. I think it's because there are other steps I have to do aside from just creating the spec.ts file and putting this code in? I've tried to solve this question by looking at other related questions and it seems like I am importing something that doesn't exist, but I don't know how to fix this issue. The failure from npm run test is very long:

```
Chrome 85.0.4183.121 (Mac OS 10.15.7) SelectiveComponent should create FAILED
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[SearchService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'SearchService', 'HttpClient', 'HttpClient' ] })
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[SearchService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:915:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11076:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11076:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:801:1)
    at ɵɵinject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:805:1)
    at Object.SearchService_Factory [as factory] (ng:///SearchService/ɵfac.js:5:41)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11243:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11065:1)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:24193:1)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:22094:1)
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/modules/dashboard/search-selective/selective.component.spec.ts:23:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:365:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:305:1)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there something like a checklist that I need to do to manually create these spec.ts files? I couldn't find anything anywhere online

Answer (score 0):

The error implies your `NavMenuComponent` has a `SearchService` service that injects the `HttpClient` service injected into it.

You can mock the dependency with jasmine. When testing components, I usually prefer to mock the direct dependencies. When testing the component you can then mock any of the `SearchService` calls.

```
describe('NavMenuComponent', () => {
  let component: NavMenuComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavMenuComponent>;
  
  // create a mock of the http client
  // the second param will be a list of functions your service has to offer
  let mockSearchService = jasmine.createSpyObj('searchService', ['search']);

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NavMenuComponent ],
      providers: [
        // provide your obj in place of the actual SearchService
        {provide: SearchService, useValue: mockSearchService}     
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavMenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I corrected it. It should have been "SearchService" because that's the direct dependency of your NavMenuComponent.